# Azure ansible dynamic inventory not working

Tags: azure, ansible-inventory

`Hello everyone,
I am facing issue with dynamic inventory for azure
Getting following error:
ansible-inventory -i test.azure_rm.yaml --graph -vvv

```
ansible-inventory [core 2.13.7]
config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible
ansible collection location = /root/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-inventory
python version = 3.10.6 (main, Nov 14 2022, 16:10:14) [GCC 11.3.0]
jinja version = 3.0.3
libyaml = True
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
host_list declined parsing /root/test.azure_rm.yaml as it did not pass its verify_file() method
script declined parsing /root/test.azure_rm.yaml as it did not pass its verify_file() method
Using inventory plugin 'ansible_collections.azu`your text`re.azcollection.plugins.inventory.azure_rm' to process inventory source '/root/test.azure_rm.yaml'
toml declined parsing /root/test.azure_rm.yaml as it did not pass its verify_file() method
[WARNING]: * Failed to parse /root/test.azure_rm.yaml with auto plugin: Failed to get credentials. Either pass as
parameters, set environment variables, define a profile in ~/.azure/credentials, or install Azure CLI and log in (az login).
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible/inventory/manager.py", line 290, in parse_source
plugin.parse(self._inventory, self._loader, source, cache=cache)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/inventory/auto.py", line 59, in parse
plugin.parse(inventory, loader, path, cache=cache)
File "/root/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/azure/azcollection/plugins/inventory/azure_rm.py", line 220, in parse
self._credential_setup()
File "/root/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/azure/azcollection/plugins/inventory/azure_rm.py", line 241, in _credential_setup
self.azure_auth = AzureRMAuth(**auth_options)
File "/root/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/azure/azcollection/plugins/module_utils/azure_rm_common.py", line 1479, in init
self.fail("Failed to get credentials. Either pass as parameters, set environment variables, "
File "/root/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/azure/azcollection/plugins/module_utils/azure_rm_common.py", line 1605, in fail
self._fail_impl(msg)
File "/root/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/azure/azcollection/plugins/module_utils/azure_rm_common.py", line 1608, in _default_fail_impl
raise AzureRMAuthException(msg)
[WARNING]: * Failed to parse /root/test.azure_rm.yaml with yaml plugin: Plugin configuration YAML file, not YAML inventory
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible/inventory/manager.py", line 290, in parse_source
plugin.parse(self._inventory, self._loader, source, cache=cache)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/inventory/yaml.py", line 114, in parse
raise AnsibleParserError('Plugin configuration YAML file, not YAML inventory')
[WARNING]: * Failed to parse /root/test.azure_rm.yaml with ini plugin: Invalid host pattern 'plugin:' supplied, ending in
is not allowed, this character is reserved to provide a port.
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible/inventory/manager.py", line 290, in parse_source
plugin.parse(self._inventory, self._loader, source, cache=cache)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/inventory/ini.py", line 136, in parse
raise AnsibleParserError(e)
[WARNING]: Unable to parse /root/test.azure_rm.yaml as an inventory source
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
> @all:
> |--@ungrouped:
```

> **Able to do** `az vm list`
> az vm list | wc -l
> 1341
> **My azure inventory yaml is below**

```
*cat test.azure_rm.yam`your text`l*
plugin: azure.azcollection.azure_rm
include_vm_resource_groups:
 - '*'
auth_source: auto
```

I've configured the credentials But I can't list the inventory using the dynamic inventory plugin. I have azure_rm.py in the same directory.`

Comment: Can you provide some details on how you setup the credentials for azure with ansible? The error seems to indicate an issue with the credentials not being present in one of the expected ways. You could try to set `auth_source: cli` if az-cli does work on the same machine ansible runs on.

Comment: @RoderickBant 
I tried with the `auth_source: cli`. It doesn't work for me.
And please find my credential file below:
root@abhay-os-factory:~/azure-suse-hostname-testing# cat /root/.azure/credentials
`[default]
tenant="************************"
subscription_id="*******************"
secret="*************************"
client_id="*************************"`